# Rewriting Text-blocs

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

I have three sets of text blocs (actually many more...) which show part of a complete text. However the partitioning of the original text was not done correctly as some sentences were split between two text blocks.

```
text1 = {"We will talk about data about model specification parameter \
estimation and model application and the context where we will apply \
the simple example.Is an application where we would like to analyze \
the market for electric cars because"};

text2 = {"we are interested in the market of electric cars.The choice \
that we are interested in is the choice of each individual to \
purchase an electric car or not And we will see how"};

text3 = {"to address this question. Furthermore, it needs to be noted that this is only a model text and there is no content associated with it. "};
```

For instance `text2` starts with "we are interested in the market of electric cars." This is an incomplete first sentence, which actually started in text block 1 (see last sentence there).

I want to make sure that each text block ends with a complete sentence. So I want to move incomplete first sentences to the last text block.  For instance here, the result would be:

```
 text1corr = {"We will talk about data about model specification parameter \
    estimation and model application and the context where we will apply \
    the simple example.Is an application where we would like to analyze \
    the market for electric cars because we are interested in the market of electric cars."};

text2corr = {"The choice that we are interested in is the choice of each individual to purchase an electric car or not And we will see how to address this question."};

text3corr = {"Furthermore, it needs to be noted that this is only a model text and there is no content associated with it. "};
```

**How can I do it in Mathematica ? Is this even possible ?**

Comment: "I want to move incomplete first sentences to the last text block." I read this, then I read your examples, and I don't see the connection.

Comment: @C.E. See how text-block 2 starts with ""we are interested in the market of electric cars." ... this is an incomplete first sentence, which actually started in text block 1 (see last sentence there). So I would like to attach it to text-block 1 and delete it from text block 2. Is that helping ?

Comment: @C.E. I edited my question.

Comment: ok, I see it now.

Comment: can we assume that we know the ordering of blocks?

Comment: in the third line `"... the simple example.Is an application ..." should be `"... the simple example is  an application ..."`, no?

Comment: @kglr Yes, that would be nice. However the original text was written like this. There are more of such errors in the entire text, but I don't know how to fix that automatically. The text is too log to go through it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update2:** Using `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
ClearAll[correct]
correct = {StringRiffle@#} & /@ ReplaceRepeated[#, 
 {a___, {b___, c_String?(Not[StringMatchQ[StringTrim@#, "*."]] &)}, {d_,  e___}, f___} :>
   {a, {b, c, d}, {e}, f}] & @
    (TextSentences /@ StringReplace[First /@ #, "." ~~ a: LetterCharacter :> ". " <> a]) &

correct @{text1,text2,text3} ==  {text1corrected, text2corrected , text3corrected }
```

> True

```
{StringRiffle@#} & /@ 
  ReplaceRepeated[#, {a___, {b___, c_String?(Not[StringMatchQ[StringTrim @ #, "*."]] &)}, 
    {d_, e___}, f___} :> {a, {b, c, d}, {e}, f}] & @ sents
```

**Update:** If text blocks are already made:

```
texts = First /@ {text1, text2, text3}; 
sents = TextSentences /@ StringReplace[texts, "." ~~ a : LetterCharacter :> ". " <> a];
sents2 = If[StringMatchQ[StringTrim[#[[1, -1]]], "*."], #[[1]], 
     Append[#[[1]], #[[2, 1]]]] & /@ Partition[sents, 2, 1, 1] ;
{text1corrected, text2corrected , text3corrected } = {StringRiffle @ #} & /@ 
  FoldList[If[#[[-1]] == #2[[1]], Drop[#2, 1], #] &, sents2]
```

> {{"We will talk about data about model specification parameter estimation and model application and the context where we will apply 
>   the simple example. Is an application where we would like to analyze 
>   the market for electric cars because we are interested in the market 
>   of electric cars."},
>   {"The choice that we are interested in is the 
>   choice of each individual to purchase an electric car or not And we 
>   will see how to address this question."},
>   {"Furthermore, it needs to 
>   be noted that this is only a model text and there is no content 
>   associated with it. "}}

**Original answer:**

Taking a step back and doing the chunking of the original text to make sure that sentences are not broken:

(1) Use [`TextSentences`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextSentences.html) to split the source text into `sentences`.

(2) If needed, use `Split` to split `sentences` into chunks subject the constraint that chunk sizes cannot exceed `maxchunksize`. The function `chunk` below does this:

```
ClearAll[chunk]
chunk[sentences_, maxchunksize_] := Module[{t = 0}, Split[sentences,  
  Or[(t += StringLength[#]) <= maxchunksize - StringLength[#2],  t = 0] &]]
```

**Example:**

```
loremipsum = StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}], 600]
```

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer 
>       nunc augue, feugiat non, egestas ut, rutrum eu, purus. Vestibulum 
>       condimentum commodo pede. Nam in metus eu justo commodo posuere. Nunc 
>       varius dui id nulla. Fusce porttitor pretium leo. Quisque in diam. 
>       Nulla pellentesque. Donec vitae urna et arcu lobortis varius. Aenean 
>       velit eros, varius ac, semper sit amet, lacinia eget, sem. Phasellus 
>       mollis nunc a pede cursus fermentum. Proin et odio. Nullam turpis. 
>       Fusce eget arcu. Mauris placerat ultricies lectus. Nullam pede nisl, 
>       ullamcorper ullamcorper, hendrerit sit amet, molestie ac,"

```
sentences = TextSentences[loremipsum ]
```

> {"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
>   "Integer nunc augue, feugiat non, egestas ut, rutrum eu, purus.",
>   "Vestibulum condimentum commodo pede.",
>   "Nam in metus eu justo commodo posuere.",
>    "Nunc varius dui id nulla.",
>   "Fusce porttitor pretium leo.",
>   "Quisque in diam.",
>   "Nulla pellentesque.",
>   "Donec vitae urna et arcu lobortis varius.",
>    "Aenean velit eros, varius ac, semper sit amet, lacinia eget, sem.",
>    "Phasellus mollis nunc a pede cursus fermentum.",
>   "Proin et odio.",
>   "Nullam turpis.",
>    "Fusce eget arcu.",
>   "Mauris placerat ultricies lectus.",
>   "Nullam pede nisl, ullamcorper ullamcorper, hendrerit sit amet, molestie ac,"}

```
Length @ sentences
```

> 16

```
StringLength[sentences]
```

> {57, 62, 36, 38, 25, 28, 16, 19, 41, 65, 46, 14, 14, 16, 33, 75}

```
maxchunksize = 200;
chunks = chunk[sentences, maxchunksize]
StringJoin /@ chunks
```

> {"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Integer 
>   nunc augue, feugiat non, egestas ut, rutrum eu, purus.Vestibulum 
>   condimentum commodo pede.Nam in metus eu justo commodo posuere.",
>   "Nunc varius dui id nulla.Fusce porttitor pretium leo.Quisque in 
>   diam.Nulla pellentesque.Donec vitae urna et arcu lobortis 
>   varius.Aenean velit eros, varius ac, semper sit amet, lacinia eget, 
>   sem.",
>    "Phasellus mollis nunc a pede cursus fermentum.Proin et 
>   odio.Nullam turpis.Fusce eget arcu.Mauris placerat ultricies 
>   lectus.Nullam pede nisl, ullamcorper ullamcorper, hendrerit sit amet, 
>   molestie ac,"}

```
Length@chunks
```

> 3

```
StringLength /@ StringJoin /@ chunks
```

> {193, 194, 198}

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately,  I can't do that. :( The text blocs are already made. They were extracted from subtitles from videos and there size varies a lot.  I want to keep the original size of the text block but simply make sure that each last sentence is not cut into two blocks. Is that possible ?

Comment: @james, please see the update.

Comment: Wow! Very nice answer ! Thanks a lot !! Would you mind to explain what "~~ a : LetterCharacter :> ". " <> a" does ?

Comment: @james, it puts a space after `"."` . `TextSentences` doesn't treat  `"."` as the end of a sentence if it is  immediately followed by a letter character.